# How to manage state in application and URL?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, url, state

I'm building a web application that manages state internally and via the URL, to allow the user to manipulate state with the browser buttons as well as the site's UI.

I'm using [jQuery-BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) to manage the URL hash, and I have a handler on hashchange that changes things accordingly when the URL changes (e.g. browser back/forward button presses).  However, the things changed accordingly themselves my end up changing the hash, thus triggering the hashchange handler and resulting in a loop.

To get around these scenarios, I find myself checking if the new state is the same as the previous, and bailing if so.  But I'm quickly getting pretty spaghettified code, addressing each state separately with multiple actors operating on each state.

Is there a design pattern that handles this kind of state management scenario gracefully?

Comment: perhaps i wasn't clear in my question that i'm not looking for alternatives to using a URL hash; more generally, i'm trying to find a way to manage state when changes can be coming from multiple inputs (UI, browser state/URL) and can affect multiple parts of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i ended up doing is being rigorous about providing only one place in my program in which state can be changed, and routing all state changes through that one place.

by 'one place', i mean one group of publicly-accessible functions whose job includes:

1. validating requested state change
2. verifying new requested state change is different than current state
3. updating application state
4. updating browser state

step 2 is perhaps most important -- it ensures that whether the state change request is coming from within the application or from the browser, there will not be any repeated attempts to change state in the application or the browser beyond the initial change.

so far so good, this seems to encapsulate the complexity of the state machine in one part of my code, making it much easier to keep things straight...still, i welcome any other answers.  i'm positive this is a problem that's been solved many times over.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot recommend you on any specific design pattern to implement right now, but I can suggest that you take a look at html5's pushSate() and popState() functions. These functions are capable of storing states as well as data that are tied to those states. github.com is using this technique to traverse thru the directories of a certain public repository. Here's a quick guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history. Hope this helps.

Comment: yep, jQuery-BBQ uses push/popState internally, and its API uses those function names.